# Raspberry Pi 4 - Internet issues

Tags: internet

I recently lent my Raspberry Pi 4 to a friend (big mistake). When I got it back, the red light on the Pi wasn't working anymore, and the pi doesn't want to connect to the internet. Neither Ethernet nor the onboard Wifi work at the moment.

The ethernet cable and port on my router works for another Raspberry Pi 2 that I own. So, I know the problem is with this specific Pi. I'm using the official Raspberry Pi power supply. It boots and I'm able to login using a monitor. SSH doesn't work obviously. The red light never turns on during startup or when it's running.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: maybe *your friend* dicked around with the operating system ... try a fresh install

Answer (score 0):

For ["red light"](https://community.element14.com/products/raspberry-pi/f/forum/9157/raspberry-pi-3-b-broken-no-green-light#:%7E:text=The%20Red%20LED%20on%20the,bad%20USB%20cable%2C%20bad%20adapter%E2%80%A6) are you referring to the one on the board? If so that is only indicative of power. But if you are able to turn it on and connect to a monitor then clearly power is not the issue.
Are your ethernet ports yellow and green blinking/on when you connect the ethernet cable? On the board do you notice any damage to the ethernet port?
Try listing your [network interfaces](https://linuxhint.com/list_network_interfaces_debian/) and see what you get.
Or do what is posted in the comment from Jaromanda X and do a fresh intall.

Comment: Yes that's the light I'm referring to. The red power led doesn't light up at all anymore. And the lights on the ethernet port also don't work. I just connected a USB to Ethernet adapter to the USB port. The Pi now has an active internet connection. Maybe the onboard ethernet port is destroyed?

Comment: Based on what you are saying:
- your power LED indicator is off
- Your ethernet port on the board is not working
From what you are describing you may want to troubleshoot the hardware: get a multimeter to test the continuity of the RED LED. This will test the physical component and help determine if it was damaged. If hardware is fine check if it was disabled https://raspberrytips.com/disable-leds-on-raspberry-pi/
Regarding the ethernet port do you observe any physical damage?
You may be better off to just ask your friend what he did with the pi while it was in their possession.